# Avoid PLE drops while performing DELETE operations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If my quesion is not specific enough please tell what details are missing. 
We are runing daily archive operations on the whole database where we keep data from the last 30 days. We are deleting data in 100 records batches. For one particular table Which has the biggest(in terms of size) records it take around 3-5 hours to delete all 2 millions of old records even just after index maintenance operations. Also deletions of that particular table causes PLE to drop. My question is how to accelerate that proces and avoid PLE drops?

Comment: PLE is simply indication of lot of I/O activity going on, if your priority is archive job just ignore it . It is *not* always indication of something bad is going. Would you be able to add more RAM to system,  if yes, go ahead do it this is give relief to PLE drop.

Comment: Have you considered increasing the batch size? 2M/100 = 20 000 batches, which will introduce unnecessary overhead. Measure with, say, 1k -10k - 100k deletes per batch (and mind the transaction log whilst you are at it).

Answer (score 0):

> For one particular table Which has the biggest(in terms of size)
>   records it take around 3-5 hours to delete all 2 millions of old
>   records

we need more detail like table structure along with data type and index details.

Try opposite method.

Keep data of last 30 days and truncate old table.

For example (Step 1),

> ```
> declare @CurDate datetime=getdate()
>
> select * 
> into NewTable
> from ExistingTable 
> where datecol >= @CurDate and datecol <= dateadd(day,-30,@CurDate)
> ```

2. Rename old table to anything unique or drop table as per requirement. In fact drop table only after testing and approval from other.
3. Rename new table to existing table